# My code won't knit in R Studio

Tags: r, rstudio

I am new to R studio and my professor gave us unknittable code. I have no idea how to fix it. Can someone please explain what the error message means and how I can fix it?

my code:

````
```{r}
PlotSpecies <- function(s, title="Species") {
s.table <- table(s)
par(las=2)
barplot(s.table, names.arg=names(s.table), 
      horiz=TRUE, cex.names=0.5, main=title)
}
```

Error message: Error in parse(text + x, srcfile = src):
<text>:11:24: unexpected symbol 10: EW <- rep(species,                                  endemic.woodland) 11: PlotSpecies(EW, title="Endemic ^ Calls: 
<Anonymous> ... evaluate -> parse_all -> parse_all.character -> parse                                                  Execution halted
````

Comment: does your code run outside of knitr?

Comment: The error message and your code don't match.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me using Markdown in the latest RStudio version (0.99.903). I just opened a new Markdown doc, copied your code, and it printed it out in a document.

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy + paste this code from a PDF, or something similar? There's a known bug in RStudio where this can cause strange parser errors when attempting to execute such code.

The simplest fix is to download and use the [preview release of RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/).